# file upload fields get the empty value

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, ext.net

here is the my problem.I am adding fileuploadfields dynamically and add each fileupload fields to the collection something like this

```
static List<FileUploadField> fuploadcollection = new List<FileUploadField>();
```

,so far so good .but when I tring to upload images inside the fileuploadfield,I getting empty fileupload field.but it seems filled "fuploadcollection"  collection when I watch it by breakpoint.

here is the my code ;

addfileupload function;

```
    public partial class UserControl1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        static int? _currentflag = 0;

        static List<FileUploadField> fuploadcollection = new List<FileUploadField>();

........
........
.........
       protected void addImages_Click(object sender, DirectEventArgs e)
            {
                int? nn = null;

                X.Msg.Alert("hello", "hello").Show();
                _currentflag = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtcurrentflag.Text)) ? Convert.ToInt32(txtcurrentflag.Text) : nn;
                FileUploadField fileUploadField = new FileUploadField()

                {
                    ID = "FileUploadField" + _currentflag,
                    Width = 280,
                    Icon = Icon.Add,
                    ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static,
                    Text = "Göz at",
                    FieldLabel = "Resim-" + _currentflag,
                    Flex = 1,
                    ButtonText="resim seç"

                };

                fileUploadField.AddTo(this.pnlResim, true);
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtcurrentflag.Text) || txtcurrentflag.Text == "0")
                {
                    fuploadcollection.Clear();
                }
                fuploadcollection.Add(fileUploadField);

                _currentflag++;
                txtcurrentflag.Text = _currentflag.ToString();


            }
```

here is the this part which give the error(coulnt enter the if statement)
* but it seems fuploadcollection filled (forexample count of it  shows more then 1 )

```
            foreach (var item in fuploadcollection)
                {
                    if (item.HasFile)
                    {
                        string resimadi = UploadImage.UploadImages(item);
```

Comment: what is the exception you get?

Comment: no exception just fileupload fields empty

Comment: what value you give to txtcurrentflag text box?

Comment: when ever clcik the add button it increase the number 1,and started with 1 and ,increase whenever clciked the add button

Comment: <input id="FileUploadField2-button-fileInputEl" class="x-form-file-input" type="file" size="1" name="FileUploadField2">

Comment: <input id="FileUploadField1-button-fileInputEl" class="x-form-file-input" type="file" size="1" name="FileUploadField1">

Comment: forexample when click the 2 times clciked the add button my firebug says this

Comment: txtcurrentflag text box default value is 0,   <ext:TextField runat="server" ID="txtcurrentflag" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="0">
                        </ext:TextField>

Answer (score 2):

If you create dynamic controls you should recreate them during each request. There are some links, which could be helpful:

http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?19315

http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?19079

http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?9224

http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?16119

http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?23402